# RxAlmofire pass parameters to requestJSON [:]

Tags: ios, swift4, rx-swift, reactive, rxalamofire

Following is method provided by **RxAlamofire** for making requestJSON request there is no method to pass parameters [String : String]

```
RxAlamofire.requestJSON(.get, url)
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (r, json) in
            if let jsonResult = JSON(json) as? JSON {
                if let foodMenuResult = MenuResult(jsonResult) as? MenuResult {
                    self?.delegate?.showMenu(menuResult: foodMenuResult)
                }
            }

            }, onError: {  [weak self] (error) in
                self?.delegate?.onError()
            },onCompleted: {})
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

How to pass parameters to **RxAlamofire** requestJSON method

Comment: You mean query parameters that go in the URL?

Comment: Yes how to add query string parameters to url when using rxalmofire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct the `URL` from `URLComponents`.

```
var components = URLComponents(string: "https://www.example.com/path")!
components.queryItems = [
    .init(name: "param1", value: "value1"),
    .init(name: "param2", value: "value2"),
]

let url = components.url!
```

The `url` above will be

```
https://www.example.com/path?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

The use of `!` should not be problematic above as the data you are passing should be valid. Please refer to the documentation of these methods though to assess the requirement for proper `nil` handling.